# What is the add-addition equivalent of edit?

Tags: word-choice

"The addition of so many accounts will be difficult".

How would I say this if had to replace "addition" with "edit"? I know modification would mean the same thing but I want to know how will I construct this sentence if I had to use "edit".

Comment: What do you think of reformulating it as "Editing so many accounts will be difficult"?

Comment: @Konstantin: Though that conveys the meaning, it isn't exactly what I am looking for. I just want to replace "addition" with the equivalent for "edit".

Comment: So much handwringing over an unnecessary definite article...

Comment: In case you weren't aware, while in contemporary usage, ***edition*** is almost always used as a noun, historically and rarely in modern times, it has seen use as a verb as well (precisely analogous to *add* -> *addition*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your comment that the reformulation "Editing so many accounts will be difficult" is not what you want, I would simply recommend "The editing of so many accounts will be difficult".

Even though it doesn't sounds that "elegant", it should be correct.

Another possibility, which comes to my mind, would be "The editing process of so many accounts will be difficult"